# When I import a . CSV file in Excel, some columns appear with truncated data, in scientific notation

Tags: excel, powerquery

When I import a .CSV file in Excel, some columns appear with truncated data.

Using the Power Query Editor, even selecting a specific column, and clicking "Data Type", regardless of the selected value (e.g., Text), the cell value is not updated to the correct one. What I've been looking for is to present the correct values of the columns "Column2", "Column3", etc.,

In the image, I refer to the data presented in scientific notation, in which it does not present the correct value of the account ID, composed of 12 numeric characters.

There is no way for me to post any code, and I cannot post the spreadsheet as an attachment, because it is confidential information of the company I work for.

I don't know how I can fix this, could someone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUGx9.png)

Steps I've already taken in an attempt to resolve the issue:

- Open MS Excel, select the "Data" tab and import the file in .csv format
- After connecting the database on my local computer, I selected the "Transform data" option[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC0jH.png)
- After that, I identify the column that I am interested in getting the data in its correct form, and try to change its "data type" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7RpM.png)
- Opening the file, either in Notepad or MS Excel, the data is presented in scientific notation, for data with values greater than 12 characters
- If you open a CSV containing the value 1,4093656325971, it will display as 1,40936E+11
- If you format it as text the display does not change. If you format the cell as Number (preventing the change of display to exponential notation) the result is 409360000000

Regardless of the attempts, I am not successful.
What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])   reads in either 1.4093656325971 or "1.4093656325971" perfectly fine. Post your code

Comment: If you **OPEN** your original `*.csv` file in **NotePad**, and it is showing the values in scientific notation, importing it into Excel cannot change that. There is a problem in your `*.csv` file.  Post a sample `*.csv` file (as text which can be copy/pasted) that demonstrates the problem. Do NOT post real data; just make something up that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are European and expect your decimal separator to be a comma character then you must select the option that does that.  Once you tell it you are European/East Atlantic those separators behave as you expect.

[Here's how to select your number format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-regional-format-settings-in-excel-for-the-web-c206344b-0d45-4a82-8eee-34ff6b008e9c)